# How can I adjust the size of the square brackets in the equation?

Tags: brackets, subscripts

I am trying to write an equation that includes fractions and the power of fractions. Here is my equation.

```
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:vlj}
       \si{\volt\of{LJ}}= \varepsilon\Bigl[{\left(\frac{r_\textsubscript{0}}{r}\right)}^{12}-   {\left(\frac{r_\textsubscript{0}}{r}\right)}^{6}\Bigr]
    \end{equation}
```

And the output is:

[image]

And i don' t like the position of the subscripts and superscripts nor the size of brackets how can I change them to have nice looking form ? I' d like to have bigger brackets and the sub and superscripts should be covered by them.

and I am using the packages:

```
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
```

Comment: The position of the superscripts is affected by the `{}` you have around the left-right (and also by the fact that you use left-right rather than `\bigl...\bigr`  Since you are manually choosing the size of the `[` then if you want them to be larger use (say) `\biggl` or `\Biggl` instead.  (Please always post complete documents showing all packages used (I don't recognise textsubscript for example)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- actually, the size of the subscript `0` (forced by `\textsubscript`) is what makes the parentheses, and therefore the outer brackets, look too small, because it raises the `r`s in the numerators.  although slightly larger brackets wouldn't be inappropriate, the brackets shown wouldn't look nearly so bad if it weren't for that "high" `r` in the numerators.

Answer (score 3):

Using `\left[` and `\right]` would get you better outer brackets:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:vlj}
   \varepsilon\left[\left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^{12}-\left(\frac{r_0}{r}\right)^{6}\right]   
\end{equation}
```

[image: Output]

EDIT:

removed some unnecessary brackets and `\textsubscript`

Comment: I'd remove the mysterious `\textsubscript` command: `r_{0}` is more than sufficient. And also the braces around `\left...\right`

Comment: @Timebandit thanks. Though I' d prefer the smaller size of subscripts. How is it possible ?

Comment: @Yirmidokuz -- smaller (actually, normal sized for this environment) subscripts are produced by `r_0` (or `r_{0}` as in the comment by egreg).  `\textsubscript` forces a size that isn't appropriate here.  in addition, the larger subscript forces the `r` to be higher than normal, causing the size of the parentheses to appear incorrect.