# Math Mode Brackets

Tags: math-mode, brackets, mode

Has anyone noticed that in math mode, the brackets do not scale? As in, they all remain the same size and looks somewhat unprofessional and cluttered. I cannot use the `\[` `\]` method because I need the equations to be labeled on the side: (1), (2), etc. as normal; it's a stupid requirement I know. Any suggestions on how to bend math mode?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. For scaling you can use fixed scaled or automatically scaled size. For example `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`, ... etc or `\left(` and `right)`. For more read some introductory text about writing math with latex. For example https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics (Automatic sizing, Manual sizing)

Comment: Automatically scaling fences by default is a very bad idea as it often leads to excessive scaling especially in math in the text, which then disturbs line spacing.

Comment: Various options, `\big` etc. or `\left \right`. Related questions: 
[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83286)
[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94356)
[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2607) (strangely enough there's no exact duplicate, probably because this is too basic)

Comment: You can try `\usepackage{nath}`.

Comment: "Has anyone noticed that in math mode, the brackets do not scale? " brackets scale when specified as delimiters, if you want them to scale but they are not scaling, presumably there is an error in your code, but as you have not shown any code, it is hard to help.

Comment: @HenriMenke Provided `amsmath` is not loaded, which is quite a difficult requirement.

Comment: It sounds like you're thinking of the `cases` environment.  Maybe this will help: [Using numcases with cases](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/476343)